# EMR - Issue in running Pig Script on from S3

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-pig, amazon-emr

I tried running the Pig script on EMR like:

pig -f s3://bucket-name/loadData.pig

But it fails with error:

ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. null

java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.pig.impl.io.FileLocalizer.fetchFilesInternal(FileLocalizer.java:778)
        at org.apache.pig.impl.io.FileLocalizer.fetchFiles(FileLocalizer.java:746)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerJar(PigServer.java:458)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processRegister(GruntParser.java:433)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:445)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:194)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:170)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:479)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:159)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:187)

The loadData.pig look like :

```
A = load '/ajasing/input/input.txt' USING PigStorage('\t', '-noschema');
store A into '/ajasing/output1444/input1444.txt';
```

I am running the Pig version 0.11.1, hadoop version 1.0.3 and AMI version 2.4.6.

If i execute this pig locally i.e by copying pig script locally on EMR cluster it works fine. But, if pig script source is s3 it fails with above mentioned error.

Please let me know what can be issue here.

Comment: Just to add i tried running like pig -f s3n://ajasing/script/loadData.pig. But same issue.

Comment: try `cd`-ing to your `s3` bucket and then running `$ pig -f ./loadData.pig`

Comment: I didn't get how can we do cd-ing into s3 bucket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you loading any .jar files?
I just had the exact problem which I solved by changing

```
REGISTER /home/hadoop/mongo-java-driver-2.11.1.jar;
```

to

```
REGISTER file:/home/hadoop/mongo-java-driver-2.11.1.jar;
```

following this post:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=480997

worked like a charm!